# SKLearn - Unusually high performance with Random Forest using a single feature

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest

I am using Random Forest as a binary classifier for a dataset and the results just don't seem believable, but I can't find where the problem is.

The problem lies in the fact that the examples are clearly not separable by setting a threshold, as the values for the feature of interest for the positive/negative examples are highly homogeneous. When only a single feature is used for binary classification, RF should only be able to discriminate between examples by setting an absolute threshold for positive/negative identification, right? If that's the case, how can the code below result in perfect performance on the test set?

P.S. In practice I have many more than the ~30 examples shown below, but only included these as an example. Same performance when evaluating >100.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

X_train = np.array([0.427948, 0.165065, 0.31179, 0.645415, 0.125764,
                    0.448908, 0.417467, 0.524891, 0.038428, 0.441921,
                    0.927511, 0.556332, 0.243668, 0.565939, 0.265502,
                    0.122271, 0.275983, 0.60786, 0.670742, 0.565939,
                    0.117031, 0.117031, 0.001747, 0.148472, 0.038428,
                    0.50393, 0.49607, 0.148472, 0.275983, 0.191266,
                    0.254148, 0.430568, 0.198253, 0.323144, 0.29869,
                    0.344978, 0.524891, 0.323144, 0.344978, 0.28821,
                    0.441921, 0.127511, 0.31179, 0.254148, 0, 0.001747,
                    0.243668, 0.281223, 0.281223, 0.427948, 0.548472,
                    0.927511, 0.417467, 0.282969, 0.367686, 0.198253,
                    0.572926, 0.29869, 0.570306, 0.183406, 0.310044,
                    1, 1, 0.60786, 0, 0.282969, 0.349345, 0.521106,
                    0.430568, 0.127511, 0.50393, 0.367686, 0.310044,
                    0.556332, 0.670742, 0.30393, 0.548472, 0.193886,
                    0.349345, 0.122271, 0.193886, 0.265502, 0.537991,
                    0.165065, 0.191266])
y_train = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
                    1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
                    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
                    1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
                    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])


X_test = np.array((0.572926, 0.521106, 0.49607, 0.570306, 0.645415,
                   0.125764, 0.448908, 0.30393, 0.183406, 0.537991))
y_test = np.array((1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0))

# Instantiate model and set parameters
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.set_params(n_estimators=500, criterion='gini', max_features='sqrt')

# Note: reshape is because RF requires column vector format, # but 
default NumPy is row
clf.fit(X_train.reshape(-1, 1), y_train)
pred = clf.predict(X_test.reshape(-1, 1))

# sort by feature value for comparison
o = np.argsort(X_test)

print('Example#\tX\t\t\tY_test\tY_true')
    for i in o:
        print('%d\t\t\t%f\t%d\t%d' % (i, X_test[i], y_test[i], pred[i]))
```

Which then returns:

```
Example#    X           Y_test  Y_true
5           0.125764    0   0
8           0.183406    0   0
7           0.303930    1   1
6           0.448908    1   1
2           0.496070    1   1
1           0.521106    1   1
9           0.537991    0   0
3           0.570306    0   0
0           0.572926    1   1
4           0.645415    0   0
```

How can an RF model with a single feature possibly discriminate these examples? Isn't there something wrong? I've looked into the configuration of the classifier and whatnot and can't find any problems. I was thinking that maybe it was a problem of overfitting (however I'm doing 10-fold cross validation, so that seems less likely), but then I came across this quote on the official webpage for Random Forest classification - ”Random forests does not overfit. You can run as many trees as you want.” (https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm#remarks)

Answer (score 0):

> When only a single feature is used for binary classification, RF should only be able to discriminate between examples by setting an absolute threshold for positive/negative identification, right?

Each *branch* can discriminate only by one threshold, but each tree is built up by several branches. If the X-space can be split into several intervals such that each interval has the same y-value, then as long as the classifier has enough data to get the boundaries of those intervals, it will be able to predict the test set. However, I noticed that your "test" set seems to be a subset of your train set, which defeats the purpose of having a test set. Of course if you test it on data than you trained on, the accuracy will be high. Try sorting your data by X-value, then taking X-values that aren't in your training set, but are between two adjacent X_train values that have different y-values. For instance, x=.001. You should see accuracy plummet.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! The train and test set are not actually subsets of each other, however there are examples that share the same feature value. The example that I gave is taken from the first train/test split for 10-fold cross-validation (new model instantiated each fold). One thing I should have added is that when I perform the same task using SVM, the performance is slightly worse than chance. So what I can't figure out is why the performance between RF and SVM would be so different? It's obviously not correct, but I can't find the problem.

Comment: @CuChemist SVM is designed for cases where there *is* a single threshold. They perform poorly when the boundary is complicated, expecially without any modifications based on the data.